# "Run time error 13" when inserting a column and adding a formula

Tags: excel, vba

This is simple: insert a column and add the formula to the range B2:B1. The formula works in a sheet, but not in the macro. Puts in the new column, clears the contents (just in case) goes no further:

> Run time error 13.

Here is the code:

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B2:B100").Formula = "=IF(A2=ISBLANK(TRUE),"",RIGHT(A2,2)&" / "&MID(A2,5,2)&" / "&LEFT(A2,4))"
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to delimit your `"`'s in the formula string

Comment: I do not really understand that. The formula works in a cell but not in the macro

Comment: it is taking 20151019 to 19/10/2015

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't know how to handle the quotes included within your formula - it thinks you are trying to end one string and start another.

To get around this, use double-quotes for anything contained within your formula, like so:

```
Range("B2:B100").Formula = "=IF(A2=ISBLANK(TRUE),"""",RIGHT(A2,2)&"" / ""&MID(A2,5,2)&"" / ""&LEFT(A2,4))"
```